# Track actions of paying customers

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, tracking, logging, apache-log-files

I'm looking for software that can analyze my Apache log files (or some other source) and tell me, from the visitors that actually bought something from my site, some profiling information; like time of their first visit, how long they spend on my website, what the original referral was, etc?

In principle a tool like Awstats provides a lot of information, but I'd like to have it filtered to individuals.

Edit: Instead of Apache log files / using IP addresses, I'm also happy to add something like php code to my site to identify returning visitors.

Comment: I'm not sure that the Apache log file contains enough information to be able to link log entries to past customers, simply because end users IP addresses and user agents tend to change. (?)

Comment: @w3d: True, the IP can change, but it don't think it often does here. I could also still gather useful information from the visits where the IP didn't change.

Comment: Some users are behind proxies (AOL sends everyone through proxy .. and their IP is changing for pretty much each page), although not so many (but it all depends on your customers actually). It's just not reliable enough. If logs would keep a cookie/session ID as well .. then yes -- you could track such info much easier. I personally do not know of such tool that can do this for you -- that's why we have our own tool (but it works differently -- page view is logged into DB when page is generated -- no web server logs parsed at all). It's slower .. but does the job we need.

Comment: Like bybe mentioned, Google Analytics can do pretty much everything it sounds like you're after, especially when you get into the more "advanced" functionality.  You can even set up and track goals, and funnelization.  It's an extremely powerful tool when used properly.

Answer (score 3):

Any type of logging software such as [Awstats](http://awstats.sourceforge.net/) and [Webalizer](http://www.webalizer.org/) do not contain the information you are after, you should take a look at various Analytics platforms and see what one is best suited for your business. I personally recommend [Google Analytics](http://www.google.com/analytics/) but there are many more out their to test.

Please note that all links listed below and are in no particular order. Numbers have been used for styling purposes only and should not be used to determine which one is best.

## Here is 15 Google Analytics Alternatives

1. [Reinvigorate](http://www.reinvigorate.net/)
2. [Stat Counter](http://statcounter.com/)
3. [Clicky](http://clicky.com/)
4. [Fox Metrics](http://foxmetrics.com/)
5. [Mix Panel](http://mixpanel.com/)
6. [Kiss Metrics](http://www.kissmetrics.com/)
7. [Extreme Tracking](http://extremetracking.com/)
8. [Site Meter](http://www.sitemeter.com/)
9. [Go Squared](http://www.gosquared.com/)
10. [Woopra](http://www.woopra.com/)
11. [Chart Beat](http://chartbeat.com/)
12. [Mint](http://haveamint.com/)
13. [Go Stats](http://gostats.com/)
14. [Stat 24](http://www.stat24.com/en/)
15. [Yahoo Web Analytics](http://web.analytics.yahoo.com/)

### Here is a list of 4 Self Hosted Analytics Software Apps

1. [PiWiki](http://piwik.org/)
2. [Crazy Egg](http://www.crazyegg.com/)
3. [Open Web Analytics](http://www.openwebanalytics.com/)
4. [Trace Watch](http://www.tracewatch.com/)

### Here is a list of 8 Log File Analyzers

I've included these in case you want to use both a logging and Analytics solution which many do use in combo with one another.

1. [Analog](http://www.analog.cx/)
2. [AwStats](http://awstats.sourceforge.net/)
3. [Deep Log File Analyzer](http://www.deep-software.com/)
4. [Weblog Expert](http://www.weblogexpert.com/)
5. [Webalizer](http://www.webalizer.org/)
6. [W3Perl](http://www.w3perl.com/)
7. [Jaw Stats](http://www.jawstats.com/)
8. [Going Up](http://www.goingup.com/)

Comment: Thanks for the effort, but this doesn't really help; I rather have one link to something which is good than a complete list of everything: I can Google for the latter but not for the former.

Comment: Please note if you actually read my answer you can see that my answer was Google Analytics which will do the job though tracking campaigns. The later solutions were give not only to enhance the answer for other people with the same question but to give you some other possibilities should you want to try something else rather than Google.

Answer (score -1):

I found from google, **Webalizer** which is a fantastic, free web server log file analyzer. It is fast and generates very nice statistical reports about who is hitting your site and what they are hitting. It can be found at mrunix.net/webalizer. Good luck. It had worked well for me long time ago.

Comment: Although bybe already covers "Webalizer" in his answer.