# Seekins statistics package which shows IP address and browser version

Tags: tracking, statistics, awstats

I am looking at my AwStats results and see 11% of my visits are from MS IE 6.

That sounds weird, and I would like to find out who it is. I suspect that if I can find a statistics package which shows IP address and browser version then I will see that all of those hits come from one IP address (or range) and I can try to figure out who and encourage them to upgrade.

I would like to recode my website in HTML 5, but can't do so if I have to spend the extra effort.

I *could* just detect the browser version and display some text encouraging browser upgrade, but would like to find out who it is.

Any advice? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most web applications that run on your own server will do this for you.

**Log Analyzers**

- [Analog](http://www.analog.cx/)
- [AwStats](http://awstats.sourceforge.net/)
- [Deep Log File Analyzer](http://www.deep-software.com/)
- [Weblog Expert](http://www.weblogexpert.com/)
- [Webalizer](http://www.webalizer.org/)
- [W3Perl](http://www.w3perl.com/)
- [Jaw Stats](http://www.jawstats.com/)
- [Going Up](http://www.goingup.com/)

**Analytics**

- [PiWiki](http://piwik.org/)
- [Crazy Egg](http://www.crazyegg.com/)
- [Open Web Analytics](http://www.openwebanalytics.com/)
- [Trace Watch](http://www.tracewatch.com/)

Some Analytics platforms that do not need to run on your own server supports this such as [Stat Counter](http://statcounter.com/), you can find many more in [another answer I provided many months ago](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/19188/track-actions-of-paying-customers/43645#43645).

Comment: I realy like statcounter. Thanks very much for the tip

Answer (score 1):

You could try [Piwik](http://piwik.org/) which is a self-hosted Analytics package.

Another alternative would be to use Google Analytics and have a custom variable for each session, which is set by your server side script (PHP, et al).