# Solution for tracking lead generations and share data with partners

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, tracking, conversions, sharing

I need to implement a lead generation feature on a website. Technically I understand how it works  (e.g. `Javascript` script associated with the `onlick` event of a button which sends data about the user to a tracking system before triggering the action, such as redirecting user to another website, revealing an email address or phone number...) however what I need is a tracking system which my partners will trust and with which I can share the collected data.

[I know one can use `Google Analytics` to track actions](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/eventTrackerGuide) (such as lead generation) but the problem is that the data sharing features of `GA` are too limited: I can only decide which profiles (i.e. websites) a user can see, but not what for that profile (so it's all or nothing).

**Does anybody know about a web analytics solution which match the following criteria?**
-allows tracking click events (similar way as `GA`)
-enables me to share analytics about 1 particular tracking code only with another user
-is free (ideally)
-is used by a few big names so that my partners will trust it (ideally)

Comment: Most online Analytics will fulfill your requirements, sadly some are not free, your find many suggestions I left in another similar question: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/19188/track-actions-of-paying-customers/43645#43645

Answer (score 1):

Try Piwik, its free.

You can even use Google Analytics for this, to share data have reports emailed to your affiliates (you don't need to give access to your GA account, just provide the email).